# Using Icon in Sitecore Code

Tags: untagged

I am using an icon in code. First I access the ThemeManager to get the URL to the icon like so:

```
  var result =  ThemeManager.GetImage(icon, 32, 32);
```

As described in https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2010/06/11/getting-the-theme-icons-from-sitecore/

However when I then render the image tag to the page the icon image is broken until I open the Icon picker in Sitecore and force the icons to be unpacked by Sitecore.

How can I force Sitecore to unpack the icons when I make the request in code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I poked around a bit through the assembly and it looks like the method you're looking for is `Sitecore.Resources.ZippedIcon.Extract(string source, string tempFileName, string zipFile)`.

It looks like the parameters you'll need are:

1. `source` - It looks like this is the relative path to the icon
2. `tempFileName` - It looks like you can get this from `FileUtil.MapPath(FileUtil.MakePath(Settings.Icons.CacheFolder, source))`
3. `zipFile` - It looks like you can get this from `Sitecore.Resources.ZippedIcon.GetZipFile(string relativeIconPath)`

I haven't had a chance to test this, but it should be a good starting point for what you're looking to do.

Answer (score 4):

I think you may just need to tweak how you are generating the icon URL.

If you're using the path that invokes the `Sitecore.Resources.IconRequestHandler`, e.g. `/~/icon/People/16x16/cubes_blue.png`, then the icon should be automatically extracted if required.

This handler uses the `ZippedIcon.GetStream` method to retrieve the file stream, and this method extracts the icon to the icon cache if necessary.